# Downloading Sentinel-2 L2A with Google Cloud BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, sentinel2

I'm trying to download Sentinel-2 data in Level 2A from Google Cloud Storage.

Level 1C works perfect with the following (already dicussed) method:
[Download script for L1C](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293024/downloading-sentinel-2-data-from-google-cloud-storage-with-python)

Now I want to do the same with L2A data but I do not know how to change the existing function `query_sentinel`.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: CSV file of the sentinel-2 data is available, which lists the available granules, their acquisition dates, and their spatial extent as minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes. The file is found in the Sentinel-2 Cloud Storage bucket: gs://gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/index.csv.gz . Is it works for you?

Comment: Yes I know. But the cool part behind the functions I use for L1C is that it works without  the csv only with google bigquery (see my link to the other post). I wonder if this is also possible for L2A?

The Problem with the csv is, that , as fas as I undertood this, I have to download the entire csv (unzipped 4 GB !!!). It would be really annoying if I want to that on a regular base. Or is it possible to use the csv without downloading?

Comment: Is there someoene who can answer my question?

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/public-datasets/sentinel-2) this index data is available in BigQuery for you to easily query using SQL.

Comment: As I already wrote above... I already did this with Sentinel-2 L1C. The actual question is, what I have to change in the script (see link in my post) to do the same with L2A???

Comment: Was this ever resolved, I would also like to query L2A, but it looks like we can only query L1C at this time.